# How can I edit a hidden input field with jquery and a textarea?

Tags: javascript

I am not sure if what I am trying to do is possible at all. Ok, so I have successfully created a "drop your images" feature for a site I am working on. This is how it looks (looks will improve).[image: This is how it currently looks]

Now, I have this textbox where I can edit the caption but I am trying to make it so that when I type the text I am able to edit parts of the hidden input box. For, example, the enter caption would edit the Caption part inside the hidden input box.

This is how it looks:

```
<input value="meta":{"userId":"le_user","FolderName":"Name Of the Folder","Caption":"","DateStamp":"","Privacy":""}">
```

This is the code I have used

```
<div class="addtextTopic">
    <div class="leimage">
     <img src="funnylookingcar.png">
     <input class="tosend" value="meta":{"userId":"le_user","FolderName":"Name Of the Folder","Caption":"","DateStamp":"","Privacy":""}">
    </div>
 <textarea class="lecaptine" placeholder="Enter A Caption"></textarea>
</div>

    $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".addtextTopic .lecaptine").onchange(function() {
               var $cap = $(this)
               $(".tosend").val($cap);
            });
        });
```

Now, the code above doesn't work, and for some reason, I am beginning to think that if it works, it will replace the entire value, instead of the caption part.

Also, am I on the right direction? is this even possible?

Comment: It would need to be `var $cap = $(this).val()` to get the value from the textarea. But yes, the result would be to replace all of the text in the hidden input. (Also, `.onchange()` should be `.change()`.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/3167/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addtextTopic .lecaptine").keyup(function() {
    var metaDefault = '"meta":{"userId":"le_user","FolderName":"Name Of the Folder","Caption":"{{CAPTION}}","DateStamp":"","Privacy":""}';
    var $cap = $(this).val();

    $(".tosend").val(metaDefault.replace('{{CAPTION}}', $cap));
  });
});
```

A few things wrong with your original code.

1. The `change` event will only fire when the textarea is blurred, not on keystroke. I changed this to `keyup`
2. I created a default string of `metaDefault` with a magic string of `{{CAPTION}}` so `.replace()` would know what to replace.
3. `$cap` needs to be the `.val()` of `$(this)`.

Comment: Looks promising.. :) +1

Comment: Oh man, it does. I was about to give up on the entire project. Wew. I will keep building it, and show off the end result once it is done. Thank you.

Comment: Sure thing. If this is the solution, please approve :)

Answer (score 0):

First change your `Onchange` method to [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) method and copy value of `.lecaptline` to `.tosend` use `$cap.val()` please find below fiddle for more info

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".addtextTopic .lecaptine").change(function() {
            debugger;
               var $cap = $(this);
               $(".tosend").val($cap.val());
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addtextTopic">
    <div class="leimage">
     <img src="funnylookingcar.png">
     <input class="tosend" value="meta":{"userId":"le_user","FolderName":"Name Of the Folder","Caption":"","DateStamp":"","Privacy":""}">
    </div>
 <textarea class="lecaptine" placeholder="Enter A Caption"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about change like this?

```
$('.addtextTopic .lecaptine').bind('input propertychange', function({

});
```